# Cannot INSERT data into mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying for two days now to figure this one out. I copied verbatim from a tutorial and I still cant insert data into a table. here is my code with form

```
<font face="Verdana" size="2"> 
<form method="post" action="Manage_cust.php" >
Customer Name 
<font face="Verdana"> 
<input type="text" name="Company" size="50"></font>
<br>
Customer Type 
<font face="Verdana"> 
<select name="custType" size="1">
  <option>Non-Contract</option>
  <option>Contract</option>
</select></font>
<br>
Contract Hours 
<font face="Verdana"> 
<input type="text" name="contractHours" value="0"></font>
<br>
<font face="Verdana">
<input type="submit" name="dothis" value="Add Customer"></font>
</form>
</font> 
<font face="Verdana" size="2">

<?php
    if (isset($_POST['dothis'])) {

    $con = mysql_connect ("localhost","root","password");
    if (!$con){
    die ("Cannot Connect: " . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("averyit_net",$con);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO cust_profile (Customer_Name, Customer_Type, Contract_Hours)   VALUES 
    ('$_POST[Company]','$_POST[custType]','$_POST[contractHours]')";

    mysql_query($sql, $con);

    print_r($sql);


    mysql_close($con);
    }
?>
```

This is my PHPmyadmin server info:

Server: 127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
Software: MySQL
Software version: 5.5.27 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version: 10
User: root@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

PLEASE tell me why this wont work. when I run the site it puts the info in and it disappears when I push the submit button, but it does not go into the table. There are no error messages that show up. HELP

Comment: try to place your query code inner try-catch, so you can track the exception

Comment: I know that this is just an example from a tutorial, but please know that taking data directly from $_POST and putting it into a SQL query is very dangerous - it's trivial for a real-world user to abuse this and read, alter or delete your database.  It's OK for learning but NEVER do this in any application that is open to the public.

Comment: @NovalAgungPrayogo There is nothing in this code that might throw an Exception.

Comment: Whoa? `<font>` tags? I'm having nightmarish flashbacks of [unmaintainable designs here](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/htmlintermediate/badtags/)

Comment: You can force PHP to show errors by adding this line to the top of the PHP code:  `error_reporting(E_ALL);`  Add this on the line after `<?php`.

Comment: I added the error reporting code, but no errors came up and it didnt post to the table. Where would these errors show up

Comment: @user2193312 Also needed is `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: @user2193312  There are serious security problems with the tutorial code.  If you are just learning and have not invested much yet, I _highly_ recommend spending your efforts on using PDO for the database interaction instead of `mysql_*()`.  The old `mysql_*()` extension is deprecated and outdated.http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: Do you have any good references for PDO tutorials

Comment: [PHP.net has PDO and mysqli examples](http://php.net)

Answer (score 0):

I have improved a little bit in your SQL statement, stored it in an array and this is to make sure your post data are really set, else it will throw a null value. Please always sanitize your input.

in your Manage_cust.php:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['dothis'])) 
{

$con = mysql_connect ("localhost","root","password");
    if (!$con)
    {
        die ("Cannot Connect: " . mysql_error());
    }

mysql_select_db("averyit_net",$con);

$company = isset($_POST['Company'])?$_POST['Company']:NULL;
$custype = isset($_POST['custType'])?$_POST['custType']:NULL;
$hours   = isset($_POST['contractHours'])?$_POST['contractHours']:NULL;

$sql = "INSERT INTO cust_profile(Customer_Name, 
                                 Customer_Type, 
                                 Contract_Hours)   
        VALUES('$company',
               '$custype',
               '$hours')
       ";

       mysql_query($sql, $con);

       mysql_close($con);
}
?>
```

Comment: Please explain for the OP what you changed and why, and also please address the SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: I tried your code and still nothing. Im going nuts over here. How can I just make sure that I even have a connection to mysql?

Comment: try to var_dump your sql statement... var_dump($sql); put it after the sql statement...what does it say?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use `font` tags...[ever](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#h-15.2)

Secondly, because of this line:

```
if (isset($_POST['dothis'])) {
```

It looks like your HTML and PHP are combined into one script? In which case, you'll need to change the action on the form to something like this:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >
```

Plus, you can kill a bad connection in one line:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","password") or die("I died, sorry." . mysql_error() );
```

Check your posts with `isset()` and then assign values to variables.

```
var $company;
if(isset($_POST['Company']) {
    $company = $_POST['Company'];
} else {
    $company = null;
}
//so on and so forth for the other fields
```

Or use [ternary operators](http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators)

Also, using the original `mysql` PHP API is usually a bad choice. It's even mentioned in the [PHP manual for the API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)

Always better to go with `mysqli` or `PDO` so let's convert that:

```
//your connection
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","averyit_net");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}


$sql = "INSERT INTO cust_profile (Customer_Name, Customer_Type, Contract_Hours) 
        VALUES ($company,$custType,$contractHours)";
            //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            //  Assuming you set these

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Someone tell me if this is wrong, so I can correct it. I haven't used `mysqli` in a while.

Comment: ok, got something different this time. the browser said that it could not connect to the web page once I hit the submit button

Comment: I tried to code a mysqli, but my notepad ++ didn't highlight it blue. I just downloading XAMPP and notepad++, so it is the latest version.

Comment: You should definitely be choosing security over syntax highlighting. Always a better choice :-)

Answer (score 0):

Change the $sql to this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO cust_profile (Customer_Name, Customer_Type, Contract_Hours)   VALUES ('".$_POST[Company]."','".$_POST[custType]."','".$_POST[contractHours]."')
```